# Get text from a foreign page in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I need to pull a section of text from an HTML page that is not on my local site, and then have it parsed as a string. Specifically, the last column from [this](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/NP/BPDLogin?application=np) page. I assume I would have to copy the source of the page to a variable and then setup a regex search to navigate to that table row. Is that the most efficient way of doing it? What PHP functions would that entail?

Comment: [curl](http://php.net/curl)/[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) for retrieval, then [DOM](http://php.net/dom) for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Scrape the page HTML with file_get_contents() (needs ini value allow_url_fopen to be true) or a system function like curl or wget
- Run a Regular Expression to match the desired part. You could just match any `<td>`s in this case, as these values are the first occurrences of table cells, e.g. `preg_match("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>/si",$html,$matches);` (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use URL fopen, then a simple file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/somepage') would suffice. There are various libraries out there to do web scraping, which is the name for what you're trying to do. They might be more flexible than a bunch of regular expressions (regexes are known for having a tough time parsing complicated HTML/XML).